# "Accumulation" points of a convergent net

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $D$ a directed set and $\phi :D \rightarrow X$ a net converging to some $x_0 \in X$. Can there be an increasing sequence $\{d_n\} \subset D$ s.t. $\{\phi(d_n)\}$ converges to some $x_1 \neq x_0$?

Comment: $\phi \circ d$ is a subnet of $\phi$

Comment: not necessarily, we don't assume $\forall d \in D$  $\exists n_0$ s.t. $n \geq n_0$ implies $d_n \geq d$...

Comment: 16015: right. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we take $D=\mathbb R\setminus \left \{0 \right \}$ and declare $x\leq y\Leftrightarrow \vert x\vert \geq \vert y\vert ,\ $then $D$ is a directed set.

Define $\phi (x)=\vert x\vert$. Then $\left \{\phi \right \}\to 0$.

Now put $d_n=1+1/n\ $and observe that $d_n$ is increasing (wrt $\leq$ on $D$), but $\phi (d_n) >1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $K_n =\{x\in X : d(x,x_0 )<n^{-1}\}.$ Let $d_1 \in D$ be such tkat $\phi (d) \in K_1 $ for $d\geq d_1 $ and let $d_n \geq d_{n-1} $ be such that $$ \phi (d) \in K_n \mbox{ for } d\geq d_1 $$ then the sequence $\phi (d_n )$ converges to $x_0.$

Comment: This gives a particular sequence $\{d_n\}$ s.t. $\phi(d_n)$ converges to $x_0$. But my question is different...